# Integrability after removing a point (integrating and discontinuity)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, proof-writing, riemann-integration

Below is a problem that I am trying to solve.

> Assume $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable.
>
> (a) Show that if one value of $f(x)$ is changed at some point $x \in
> > [a,b]$, then $f$ is still integrable and integrates to the same value
> as before
>
> (b) Show that the observation in (a) holds if a *finite* number
> of values of $f$ are changed.
>
> (c) Find an example to show that by altering a countable number of
> values, $f$ may fail to be integrable.

I began solving part (a). What I have so far:

> (a) Assume $f$ is integrable so that $U(f)=L(f)$. Now, let $g$ be the
> modified function where we have changed the value of $f$ at some
> $x_{0} \in [a,b]$. We claim that $U(g)=U(f)$ and $L(g)=L(f)$.
>
> Let $\epsilon >0$. To show that $U(g)=U(f)$, we want to find a partition $P$ for which $U(g,P)< U(f)+ \epsilon$.

I am not sure if I started on the right track, or how to continue explaining (a). Hopefully once I figure out (a), I can complete the rest. Any hints would be extremely helpful - thank you!

**Edit:** There is a similar problem that was also posted ([Integrability doesn't change if we remove one point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262825/integrability-doesnt-change-if-we-remove-one-point)), but most of the solutions appear to be building off the submitted suggestion for a proof, which I am not sure I understand. My main issue is I am having a hard time finding what I am being asked to prove. I believe I would benefit more from an explanation as to why I am not on the right track, or perhaps a hint as to what I should look at first when trying to approach the proof.

**Edit 2:** I read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3171297/real-analysis-integrable) and found it somewhat useful. It was relatively easy to follow.

Comment: What are $U(f)$ and $L(f)$?

Comment: Prove this:  *Suppose that $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is zero at every point with one solitary exception.  Then $f$  is Riemann integrable there.*   (If you cannot prove that you cannot solve your problem.)   [Your title is misleading--it has nothing to do with discontinuities.]

Comment: @Snildt $U(f)$ and $L(f)$ are the upper and lower sums of the partition $P$ of $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 2):

What the question asks is (i) start with a Riemann integrable function $f$  (ii) consider another function $g$ [not known to be integrable] (iii) assume that $f=g$ except at finitely many points. (iv) Now show that $g$ is integrable and the two integrals have the same value.

*Bad advice*: try to use the definition of the integral for $f$ and $g$ and mess around with Riemann sums or Darboux sums.  Try real hard to show $g$ is integrable without getting lost in all those inequalities, etc.

*Good advice*:  Note that $g = f -h$  where $h=f-g$ is a very simple function [it is zero except at a few points].  If both $f$ and $h$ are integrable so is $g$ etc.  *Bright idea*: focus your attention on $h$.

To make it clear so that you can see the logic in the steps:

1. Show that if $h:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is zero everywhere but with one exception, then $h$ is Riemann integrable and $\int_a^b h(x)\,dx=0$.

*Hint: get into the details of Riemann or Darboux sums for this.*

2. By induction (or otherwise) show that if a function  $h:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is zero everywhere but with finitely many exception, then $h$ is Riemann integrable and $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=0$.
3. Recall the fact that $f$ and $h$ are both Riemann integrable so too is the sum $f+h$ and the difference $f-h$.
4. Conclude that if  $f$ is Riemann integrable and $g$ differs from $f$ at a finite number of points, then $g$ is also Riemann integrable and, moreover,
   $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx= \int_a^b g(x)\,dx$.

*Hint: Write $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ and apply #2 and #3.*

---

Here is a follow-up that is more general, more interesting, but uses mostly the same ideas;

**Theorem.**  Suppose that $ f $ and $ g $ are bounded functions on an interval $ [a,b] $ and that they differ at only a finite number of points. Then
$$ \underline{\int_a^b} f(x)\,dx = \underline{\int_a^b} g(x)\,dx. $$
and
$$ \overline{\int_a^b} f(x)\,dx = \overline{\int_a^b} g(x)\,dx. $$

Then your problem is an immediate corollary.

Never be satisfied with some messy proof with $ \epsilon $s and sups/infs. Try to write up in transparent steps.

*Hint*: If $ f $ and $ g $ are bounded functions on an interval $ [a,b] $ and they differ at only a finite number of points, then take a good look at the function $ h = f-g. $ What can you say and how might that help?

**Definition**. A function $ h $ on an interval $ [a,b] $ will be called ***trivial*** if it is zero except possibly at a finite number of points.

**Lemma 1**. If $ h $ is a trivial function on an interval $ [a,b] $ then $ h $ is Riemann integrable there and $ \int_a^b h(x)\,dx =0 $.

Not hard to prove.  This was step #1 and #2 in the hints above.

**Lemma 2**. If $ f $ and $ g $ are bounded functions on an interval $ [a,b] $ then
$ \underline{\int_a^b} f(x)\,dx + \underline{\int_a^b} g(x)\,dx  \leq \underline{\int_a^b} [ f(x)+g(x)]\,dx $

This is standard and should be in any text or lecture that discusses such things. Important to know anyway. Note the inequality. Not an equality.

**Lemma 3.**  Suppose that $ f $ and $ g $ are bounded functions on an interval $ [a,b] $ and that they differ at only a finite number of points. Then
$ \underline{\int_a^b} f(x)\,dx = \underline{\int_a^b} g(x)\,dx. $
A similar statement is true for the upper integrals.

*Proof.* Let $ h = f-g $ . Then $ h $ is trivial. Apply Lemma 1 and Lemma 2 to obtain
$$ \underline{\int_a^b} g(x)\,dx = \underline{\int_a^b} g(x)\,dx + \underline{\int_a^b} h(x)\,dx $$
$$ \leq \underline{\int_a^b} [ g(x)+h(x)]\,dx = \underline{\int_a^b} f(x)\,dx .$$
Similarly
$$ \underline{\int_a^b} f(x)\,dx = \underline{\int_a^b} f(x)\,dx + \underline{\int_a^b} [- h(x)]\,dx $$
$$ \leq \underline{\int_a^b} [ f(x)+[-h(x)]]\,dx = \underline{\int_a^b} g(x)\,dx. $$

QED.

Note too this usual trick. You want to prove that $ A = B $? Well show instead that $ A\leq B $ and also that $ B\leq A $. Inequalities are very often easier than equalities.

Answer (score 1):

Objectively speaking, you are on a right track since any proof of the theorem will imply that $U(f) = U(g)$, and conversely, once you prove $U(f) = U(g)$ you are done proving the theorem since the argument for $L(f) = L(g)$ is the same.

Since $f$ and $g$ only disagree at $x_0$, one statement that is easy to prove is that for any partition $P$ of $[a, b]$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a refinement $P'$ such that $|U(f, P') - U(g, P')| \leq \varepsilon$. To prove it, just refine $P$ so that the subintervals containing $x_0$ have length $\leq \varepsilon$.

Now once you have this, you are done since by definition of $U$, there is $P$ such that
$$U(f) \leq U(f, P) < U(f) + \varepsilon$$
and by refining $P$, we can assume that
$$U(g) \leq U(g, P) < U(g) + \varepsilon,$$
$$|U(g, P) - U(f, P)| < \varepsilon$$
as well.

Note the similarity in this proof to the proof of linearity of integration, which, as the other answer alluded to, can be used to prove this theorem as well.